# Pass arguments to rqt plugin in gdb

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How I can pass arguments to a rqt plugin within gdb

```
% gdb python
(gdb) run $YOUR_RQT_GUI_HOMEDIR$/bin/rqt_gui
 :          (usual gdb usage)
```

With the code above I can start the rqt_plugin, but without arguments

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224401/pass-arguments-to-rqt-plugin-in-gdb/) by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is offtopic.

But anyways: you can pass commandline arguments (this is what your question is about, right?) to an executable in `gdb` using the `--args` option. I.e. `gdb --args executablename arg1 arg2 arg3`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on 2016-01-20**:
No, this is not possible.
For debugging a rqt_plugin I have to start "gdb python" than I am in GDB modus.
For starting the rqt_plugin I have to run the plugin like this: run $YOUR_RQT_GUI_HOMEDIR$/bin/rqt_gui
I can't start in this mode gdb --args exeName arg1 arg2 arg3